# How to Exclude those who opened an Email from a Mobile Connect Send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobileconnect

We routinely send email promos and have to follow up with an SMS to those who have not opened the email.

I know this can be done in Journey Builder with an engagement split but we can't predict which emails need an SMS message so Journey Builder is not viable.

As of now, all I can think of is to go to Tracking Sends > Email_Name > Opens > and Export the subscriber keys field of those who opened.. Create a new DE.. Upload those subscriber Keys.. Go to Automation Studio.. Create a Query to Join the Original DE with the new DE of those who opened by subscriber key.. and finally add that to the Excluded field in Mobile Connect.

It works but I would highly appreciate anyone with a better solution.

Cheers,

Comment: have you looked at the data views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a nullable empty field in your Journey Entry DE, set up the email send in Journey Builder, add a Wait step for however much time you give the customer to act, add an Engagement Split to check for an email Open, and use the Contact Update activity to write a flag back to the entry DE if there is/isn't an Open activity.

That way you'll have an ongoing and easily accessibly history of each customers' activity in the Journey, and can trigger followup SMS messages etc with very little effort.

Comment: Thank you! I rarely, use the Joureny Builder for on-the-spot sends like this since Email Studio makes it easier but this makes a lot of sense.